# Double Integral bounded by a region

Tags: integration

I wanted to evaluate $I=\iint_D xy \,dx\,dy$ where the domain of integration $D$ is in the first quadrant $\left(x\geq0,y\geq0\right)$ and is bounded by $y=x^2$, $y=x^2+4$, $y=6-x^2$, and $y=10-x^2$.

I sketched the domain of integration [domain of integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouBua.png) and found the four intersecting points of the curves as: $\left(1,5\right),\left(\sqrt3, 7\right), \left(\sqrt5, 5\right), and \left(\sqrt3, 3\right)$. Based on these information I evaluated the integral as: $I=\int_{3}^{7}\int_{1}^{\sqrt5}xy \,dx\,dy=40.$ But I am not confident about the limits of the integration, hence about the answer.

Comment: Your bounds are for a rectangular region.  The region in the problem is not a rectangle.

Comment: This is a simple yet pretty annoying exercise: draw all those parabolas and take a close look to the domain defined by these curves in the first quadrant. As Paul commented, that is far from being a rectangle as you calculated. Now, evaluate all the relevant intersection points and, perhaps, divide the integration domain in several simpler subdomains so that you'll be able to evaluate the given integral in each and at the end sum up all the results.

Answer (score 0):

The left part of the region is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{1}^{\sqrt{3}}dx \int_{6-x^2}^{x^2+4}dy  \ xy
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How about the right part? Is it something like  $\int_{\sqrt3}^{\sqrt5} dx \int_{x^2}^{10-x^2} xy dy$ ?

Comment: @SKabir thats right